# Hazelcast and Unicode

Tags: unicode, hazelcast

Does Hazelcast supports Unicode. In some comparison site I found that Unicode support is not there . But nothing as such mentioned in Official docs.

http://vschart.com/compare/hazelcast/vs/redis-database

We are looking for using Open Source version. What are the differences of the same from Enterprise edition ? Marketing points are mentioned in Site but nothing specific said as they have done a comparison chart for hazelcast vs ehcache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Hazelcast just stores serialized Java objects it does "have" Unicode support due to the fact Java Strings support Unicode.

For the question about Opensource compared to Enterprise:
Currently advanced security features like JAAS authtication and Offheap are built into the Enterprise version but more features come up in the next versions alongside with an reimplemented Offheap.